# How to return ip address from ipify function for use in other function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below works, but I want to improve it, the first iteration is useless because the real public ip address isn't assigned to myip until the second iteration. So, the code are doing n+1 iterations.

How can I use the real ip address from the first iteration? I tried callbacks, promises, generators and yields,... Nothing works and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/geoip-country
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipify

  ```
  var retry = require("co-retry");
  var geoip = require("geoip-country");
  var ipify = require("ipify");
  var myip = "0.0.0.0";

  function* getCountryCode () {
      ipify((err, ip) => {
          myip = ip;
      });
      return geoip.lookup(myip).country;
  }

  exports.retryCheckVPN = function*(){
      var job = function* (){
          var response = yield getCountryCode();
          console.log(process.env.VPN.trim() + " -- " + response);
          if(response.trim() === process.env.VPN.trim()){
              //VPN is ready, do your work
              return response;
          } else {
              throw "VPN not ready";
          }
      };
      return yield retry(job, {retries: 12, factor: 1});
  };
  ```

Comment: In the first function you return geoip.lookup(myip).country; and myip is '0.0.0.0' you should return inside the callback of ipify()

Comment: No, doesn't work, I have already tried that

Answer (score 0):

So as I comment you try this:

```
function getCountryCode (callback) {
    ipify(function(err, ip) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, geoip.lookup(myip).country);
    });
}

exports.retryCheckVPN = function(){
    getCountryCode(function(error, response){
        if (error) throw error;
        if(response.trim() === process.env.VPN.trim()){
            //VPN is ready, do your work
            return response;
        } else {
            throw "VPN not ready";
        }
    });
};
```

Sorry, I don't used to use ES6 Syntax. I know I have to learn. I have rewrited your code with callbacks.

Comment: With that the response is undefined here: 

        var response = yield getCountryCode();
        console.log(process.env.VPN.trim() + " -- " + response);

Comment: Check edit. That's how it looks your code with callbacks more or less. For your sintax as far as I know return and yield are like synonims and you're using both maybe this could be wrong.